How to link the output from a texture2D array to the vertex position in Unity URP Shader Graphs?
In unity 2022.3.7f1 URP shader graph, I am unable to link the output from a sample texture array2D to the input for vertex position, even though I am able to link it to a sample texture2D LOD.
Shader Graph overview
Here I have a unity shader graph set up so that I can loop through a 2D texture array and map it to 2 parts of my shader output. The planned outcome is to be able to displace the brighter parts of the image upwards more than the darker ones.
Connecting it to base color causes no issues, and the shader displays the color as expected on the material. However, when I attempt to link it to the vertex position, unity does not allow it.
The node does not light up or allow connections here
When using a texture2D LOD sampler, this issue does not exist, and I am not sure why this is the case.
Inputted using a Sample Texture 2D LOD, the node is able to connect
If anyone knows why this is happening and how I can make this same shader work for a gif, including alternate implementations, that would be greatly appreciated

Changing the node mip sampling mode from default to LOD solved the problem; However, I would still like to know why it doesn't work in the basic form
